# C# use callback to return to execution in called method

Tags: c#, callback, delegates, yield

I am faced with an optimization problem with reading from a FileStream and I want to build a function that can read the header of a struct then once it is finished read all the references that it came across. Is this something I can do with a callback?

Currently I am storing the reference lookup item into a queue and concatenating that queue with each new item as it is found (or using the queue function if its a single item). I return the result of this method and pass it into another method that reads the headers for all the reference objects and assigns them to the object. This is currently really bad for perf but still better than the random reads I had before.

All the reference objects exist in linear order in the FileStream in a tree structure

```
public override Queue<BlamPointer> ReadFields(BinaryReader binaryReader)
    {
        var blamPointers = new Queue<BlamPointer>(base.ReadFields(binaryReader));
        type = (Type) binaryReader.ReadInt16();
        format = (Format) binaryReader.ReadInt16();
        usage = (Usage) binaryReader.ReadInt16();
        flags = (Flags) binaryReader.ReadInt16();
        detailFadeFactor01 = binaryReader.ReadSingle();
        sharpenAmount01 = binaryReader.ReadSingle();
        bumpHeightRepeats = binaryReader.ReadSingle();
        spriteSize = (SpriteSize) binaryReader.ReadInt16();
[....]
        meleeAimAssist = new MeleeAimAssistStructBlock();
        blamPointers = new Queue<BlamPointer>(blamPointers.Concat(meleeAimAssist.ReadFields(binaryReader)));
        blamPointers.Enqueue(ReadBlockArrayPointer<BitmapGroupSequenceBlock>(binaryReader));
        blamPointers.Enqueue(ReadBlockArrayPointer<BitmapDataBlock>(binaryReader));
        return blamPointers;
    }
```

This is really bad because it creates a substantial GC footprint.

```
public virtual void Read(BinaryReader binaryReader)
    {
        var pointers = ReadFields(binaryReader);
        ReadPointers(binaryReader, pointers);
    }

public override void ReadPointers(BinaryReader binaryReader, Queue<BlamPointer> blamPointers)
    {
        base.ReadPointers(binaryReader, blamPointers);
        meleeAimAssist.ReadPointers(binaryReader, blamPointers);
        sequences = ReadBlockArrayData<BitmapGroupSequenceBlock>(binaryReader, blamPointers.Dequeue());
        bitmaps = ReadBlockArrayData<BitmapDataBlock>(binaryReader, blamPointers.Dequeue());
    }
```

I was wondering if there is a way to yield the reference 'blamPointer' function from the method that reads the 'pointer', then return to it to finish reading the reference object—using a callback function or something else?

Comment: Did you try creating a Action\Func delegate for the same ?

Comment: I was thinking about that, creating an Action and just wrapping the method into it with the parameters, but wouldn't that be worse for perf? And I'm atually using CodeDom to generate this code so it wouldn't be possible afiak.